# How to filter a relation in place

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a pretty fundamental question, I guess, but I'm having a hard time finding an answer. It may be that this just isn't a thing people do, and if that's the case I'd like to know why.

In a show action, usually I have some code like this:

`@structure = Structure.where(id: params[:id])`

This gets me a relation containing the unique structure with the given id. Structure `has_many` plannings. What I'd like is a way for my "Structure" relation to contain structures that have plannings relations that have been filtered. So, I don't want the Structures scoped to their plannings, I want the plannings on those structures to themselves have been filtered. I want to get back a relation containing a structure that has only a subset of its plannings. Does this even make sense?

**edit:**

I'm starting to see why this doesn't make sense, but also having a hard time articulating it. This,

```
@structure           = Structure.where(id: params[:id])
@structure.plannings = @structure.plannings.where(audience_ids: "1")
```

throws an error along the lines of `Cannot modify association 'Structure#plannings' because the source reflection class 'Planning' is associated to 'Course' via :has_many`. The message I'm getting here is: what you are trying to do is more complicated than you think.

I guess I should just return json that looks like what I want it to look like, rather than trying to modify the relation in place.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but it may be a misconception. If I can say "hey database give me all the structures with A, B, and C", then I feel like I should be able to say "Hey database give me all those structures, but when I ask for their plannings I only want those with D, E, and F".

Comment: It's a little unclear to me which of two things you want. Do you A) want to only get structures that have a planning matching your criteria or B) want all the structures you selected at first, but only want the plannings for those structures that have the planning criteria. If the answer is A then you'll want 'joins'. If the answer is B then 'includes' and 'scope'.

Comment: Definitely "B". The question is that I don't just want those plannings, I want a structure object with only those plannings. You know? I want it "in place". I know perfectly well how to do `Structure.where(id: params[:id]).plannings.scope("some scope")`. The question is about wanting to do this "in place" so that the relation returned is a structure with fewer places.

Comment: Then if scoping doesn't accomplish what you want I guess I need to know why you want only those plannings to be there.

Answer (score 0):

If your criteria are constantly the same for all plannings that are fetched as a structure's relation, you could use a [default scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many) in the relation (available on **Rails 4**)

```
class Structure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plannings -> { where(attribute_a: true) }
end
```

that way
`Structure.where( ... ).first.plannings`
will apply the desired scope to plannings.

Comment: I think I have asked a "wrong question". I understand this scope stuff, I understand that I can easily "get" the plannings I want. What I would like, though, is to server a Structure object that only has the desired plannings. You know what I mean? On the client side I want to never know that any other plannings exist. I thought I could accomplish this with some railsy magic, but I guess I just have to render an object that contains the plannings that I want.